# Reposition login button

Tags: swift

How do you reposition a login button to, let's say, the bottom of the `UIView`?

```
logInButton.center=self.view.center

self.view.addSubview(logInButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use storyboard for location of views? Anyway, you can do it programmatically like this:

```
let selfViewSize = self.view.frame.size
let logInButton.frame = CGRectMake((selfViewSize.width / 2) - 50, selfViewSize.height - 100, 100, 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's saying the definition conflicts with a previous value?